# Getting updated text by user of textarea jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am attempting to send updated text by user of textarea via ajax post.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="update-question button" onclick="update_question_ajax(<?php    echo $i; ?>)" style="outline: 0 none;"><?php _e('Update') ?> </button>
```

jQuery:

```
function update_question_ajax(id)
{
    var editedQuestionId = $('#question-id-' + id).val();
    var editedQuestionObj = $('.edit-question-' + id + ' textarea').val();
    var modalObj = $('#myQuestionModal');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/question/admin_edit_question'); ?>",
        data:{
            edited_question: editedQuestionObj,
            question: editedQuestionId
        },
        success: function(){
            modalObj.dialog('close');
            modalObj.html('');
            return false;
        },
        complete: function(){
            //window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

When I run this, the form_data of the textarea is the duplication of what exists in textarea before the ajax request (not-changed status by user. For ex: before the ajax call text is "question", after ajax post text is "questionquestion")

What is the problem you think?

Thank you!

Comment: Don’t use `.text()` on a textarea, use `.val()`

Comment: There's nothing in that code that sets any value to the textarea, so I'm guessing the window reload line is not commented in your code, and that the page reloads, and hence the issue is serverside ?

Comment: @CBroe I used .val() but result is same. It duplicates text!

Answer (score 0):

That code NEVER change anything of the HTML in the page (except "delete" modal box"). Check for any other jQuery functions you have in your page, the issue is not produced for the code you posted.

Comment: Then what code should I add for sending changed value of "textarea" by user via ajax?

Comment: question is: why are you getting the value in the textarea? what code from the page does it?

Comment: You're sending the value correctly with your POST, the problem, as you wrote, is the duplicated value into the textarea. In your PHP you should get the value from the AJAX request.

Comment: textarea's text is automatically filled by data from database. What I want to achive is update database with user's input (into textarea). Normally when user types something in textarea (within the form) ajax sends this actual value (written by user). In this case actually it does nothing (when I hit on "update button"). When I check FORM DATA from FIREBUG I see same value that fecthed from database not the user's one..

Comment: if so, your problem is with PHP, or with your server, did you check if the headers sent back to your browser mark if the file is cached?